# Unable to mark post's as favorites

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello everyone I am making an android application with the help of Firebase. The application is working fine but ever since I tried to add the functionality of a favorite button, I am unable to get the bug out of that "add favorite" part of the code.
    current_state="not av"
The above part states the  current favorite state of the user.
The below code is for "add favorite" part.

```
 Holder.mFavourites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (current_state.equals("not fav")){
                        mFav.child(puid).child(kk).child("fav_status").setValue("Added as " +
                                "fav").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                Holder.mFavourites.setImageDrawable(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_black));
                                current_state = "fav";
                               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Added to favourites",Toast
                                       .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }else if (current_state.equals("fav")){
                        mFav.child(puid).child(kk).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){


                                    Holder.mFavourites.setImageDrawable(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp));
                                    current_state = "not fav";
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Removed from favourites",Toast
                                            .LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });
```

I am getting a problem with the above code-
1. Whenever the first time user click on the code. He gets added to favourite and if he click again on the same button then he is removed from the favourites, but if the user after clicking once (i.e. after getting added as favourites)goes on and click on the  add to fav button again,then the toast of removed from favorites appears regardless of whether the user is in favorites database or not.

Answer (score 0):

Is current_state a class variable that equals "not fav"? Cause it looks like your if statement is just reading a string and doesnt actually know whats going on in the database. What if you query all the favs into an arraylist and test your if statement against the arraylist

Comment: Yes it's a class variable which tells the initial state of the post if it the state is "not fav" then the post is added to favorite and as soon as the post is added to favorite the current state changes to to the "fav". I got the problem and that is instead of assigning and checking the current_state to all the posts. I should check current state for each specific post but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: It looks like the problem may be that current_state doesnt actually hold the initial state of the post, Its just assuming its not fav(which may work for the first post). Then when you fav a post it changes the "current_state" to 'fav' so when you fav another post the current state is still 'fav' even though the post isn't. if you want to check the state of each post you could try putting the "current_state" inside each post in the database and check the state in the adapter.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same @ShadowSuave but the problem is that I am unable to implement it can you please give some hint on how to implement it in a code. Thanks in advance.